# Is there a way in WP e-Commerce to find out which are my best selling individual products?

Tags: wordpress, list, e-commerce, hierarchy, product

I want to do a review of my sales over the past year but am having trouble finding a way to list my sales by individual product. It allows me to list them by total amount/customer name/date etc etc, but I can't seem to break it down any further than that.

Is there a plugin that lets me see sales by individual product, or some feature within WP e-C?

Answer (score 0):

WP didn't design for e-commerce sites, I suggest if you use open cart script its very easy and very useful, and if you are looking for more advance way you can try prestashop I always recommend this its very useful and you can generate a lot of of data from it.